# Why XServer sends FocusOut notify twice

Tags: c, xlib

I write dummy window for software [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). Idea is when user switches to another machine, previous machine opens dummy window beyond the screen bounds, so emulates focus lost. Windows without focus are transparent on my system (awesome wm). If I just use `XSetInputFocus(dpy, None, RevertToNone, CurrentTime)` current window loses focus but doesn't become transparent. That is why I use dummy window.

Come to the point. My program saves focused window before opens dummy window. When dummy window loses focus program restores saved. So It needs to catch `FocusOut` event and then call `XSetInputFocus` function to restore focus. Problem is that xserver sends FocusOut notify twice. If I handle it only once program works incorrect.

Code is below.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

int x = 100, y = 100, height = 200, width = 200;

typedef struct {
    Window win;
    int notify;
} wait_arg;

Bool xevent_handler(Display *dpy, XEvent *ev, XPointer arg) {
    wait_arg *a = (wait_arg *) arg;
    return (ev->type == a->notify) && (ev->xvisibility.window == a->win);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Display *dpy;
    Window focused;
    int revert_to;
    Window win;
    wait_arg arg;
    XEvent ev;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    // Save window which has focus now
    XGetInputFocus(dpy, &focused, &revert_to);

    int s = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, s), 0, 0, height, width, 0,
            CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent);

    // Set DIALOG type for window
    Atom type = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    long value = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG", False);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, win, type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace,
            (unsigned char *) &value, 1);

    // Set events to handle
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, VisibilityChangeMask | FocusChangeMask);

    // Draw window
    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    // Wait until window stands visible, otherwise will get
    // "Error of failed request: BadMatch"
    arg.win = win;
    arg.notify = VisibilityNotify;
    XIfEvent(dpy, &ev, &xevent_handler, (XPointer) &arg);

    XSetInputFocus(dpy, win, RevertToNone, CurrentTime);
    XSync(dpy, False);

    XMoveWindow(dpy, win, x, y);

    // Wait until focus lost
    arg.win = win;
    arg.notify = FocusOut;
    XIfEvent(dpy, &ev, &xevent_handler, (XPointer) &arg);
    // Why I should handle this event twice?
    XIfEvent(dpy, &ev, &xevent_handler, (XPointer) &arg);

    // Restore focus
    XSetInputFocus(dpy, focused, revert_to, CurrentTime);
    XSync(dpy, False);
}
```

*How to check incorrect behavior:*

I comment second FocusOut handling. I use two monitors: left and right. I start program in terminal on right monitor. Program opens dummy window on left monitor. When dummy window loses focus another window on left monitor obtains it. Not terminal window on right monitor!

Why xserver sends FocusOut twice? Or it is bug/feature of my window manager?

Answer (score 1):

Without your implementation it is really impossible to know exactly what the driver is for the behavior you are seeing, but the man pages do provide some insight into what may be happening.

This particular behavior may be the result of the *last-focus-change* time.  From [this man page](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XSetInputFocus.html):

> ...The XSetInputFocus() function changes the input focus and the last-focus-change time. It has no effect if the specified time is earlier than the current
>   last-focus-change time or is later than the current X server time.

Comment: I have rewritten my question.